# Create a cumulative sum on days before without going into the future using Power Pivot

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I would like to create a pivot table using Power Pivot that does a cumulative sum of applications by days before the term.

Here is a sample of what I would like (for the date 2 days before the 2018FA term):

```
|--------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
| Term   |  5  |  4  |  3  |  2  |  1  |  0  |
|--------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
| 2016FA |  1  |  2  |  5  |  5  |  5  |  5  |
|--------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
| 2017FA |  2  |  3  |  5  |  6  |  6  |  6  |
|--------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
| 2018FA |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |     |     |
|--------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
```

A sample spreadsheet can be found here with the source data: https://1drv.ms/x/s!An5LyDXEQx2lh7AO7ecw5zpuw7grIQ

I tried the following formula with no success:

```
Applicants (PiT) [Alt]:=VAR MaxDate = MAX( Dates[Full_Date] )
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    [Applicants],
    FILTER(
        ALL( Dates ),
        'Dates'[Days_before_term] >= MAX( 'Dates'[Days_before_term] ) &&
             'Dates'[Full_Date] <= MaxDate
    )
)
```

Can someone please shed some light on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would keep your first `Applicants (PiT)` measure as is and then create a wrapper measure to blank out the dates you don't want.

Here's the counting measure:

```
Applications (PiT) =
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT(Applications[ID]),
        FILTER(
            ALL( 'Dates'[Days_before_term] ),
            'Dates'[Days_before_term] >= MAX( 'Dates'[Days_before_term] )))
        )
    )
```

And here's the wrapper:

```
Wrapper = 
    VAR MaxDate = CALCULATE(MAX(Applications[Date]), ALL(Applications))
    RETURN IF(MAX(Dates[Full_Date]) > MaxDate,
              BLANK(),
              Applications[Applicants (PiT) [Alt]]])
```

Use the wrapper measure in your table instead.

Comment: I tried this and it does not seem to work. I have created a working model using my Enrollment report (the structure is very similar). I have actually tried to do this calculation in two ways. One as described above and another I found on SQLBI. The second way leaves blanks in my chart and data. The first still does not stop displaying recent data.

https://1drv.ms/f/s!An5LyDXEQx2lh9lAaBQC-i2GG0o75w